Laragon load some php extensions on CLI but not load in Apache (curl, intl, pdo_pgsql)
I'm trying to load a php environment with Laragon in Windows 10.
When I start Apache, in php_errors.log file I get this warnings:
[13-Sep-2024 01:03:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\curl (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\php_curl.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
[13-Sep-2024 01:03:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\intl (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\php_intl.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
[13-Sep-2024 01:03:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\pdo_pgsql (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\php_pdo_pgsql.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0

When I show a phpinfo() output, effectively curl, intl and pfo_pgsql are not loaded. But if I run php -m in the terminal, the extensions are loaded.
C:\laragon\www
λ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
...
iconv
intl
json
...
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
Phar
...

The ini file is the same on CLI and Apache.
In CLI
C:\laragon\www
λ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

In Apache (using PHP Info)

The *.dlls files are present in the directory C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\ext\


The others extensions load fine (e.g. mysql)
I already reloaded Apache and restarted Windows.
The extensions are uncommented in php.ini file.


The problem it was the PHP default version of Laragon package.
I try to add new PHP versions using the links of the Wiki Page, install new PHP version 8.1.29 and enable the pdo_pgsql extension, and all works fine.
Extra info: The old version of PHP in the package was 8.1.10 and not include nts in his name. The new version is 8.1.29. IDK if this is relevant.

